# loop ggplot in preparation for cowplot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization

I ran into a problem creating ggplots in a loop. I'm very much aware of the many questions regarding this issue, but I haven't found my specific problem anywhere...

I was able to run ggplot in a loop and export every graph into a pdf (see code below).

```
for (var in unique(plot_df$ars_label)) {
  dev.new()
  print( ggplot(plot_df[plot_df$ars_label==var,], aes(x = zeit, y = sch_pro_100k)) +
           scale_x_continuous(name = "Jahr",
                              limits = c(2010,2020),
                              breaks = seq(2010,2020,2)) +
           scale_y_continuous(name = "Scheidungen pro 100k EW",
                              limits = c(145,285),
                              breaks = seq(145,285,20)) +
           geom_line(color = "steelblue4", size = 0.9) + 
           labs(title = var, 
                   subtitle = "Scheidungen pro 100 000 Einwohner\n2011-2019",
                   caption = "Daten: regionalstatistik.de\nTabellen 12631-01-02-4 und 12411-05-01-4") +
           theme_minimal() +
           theme(plot.caption.position = "panel",
                 plot.caption = element_text(color = "grey40")))
  
  ggsave(file=paste0("some/path/plot_", var,".pdf"), width = 7, height = 4, units = "in")
  dev.off()
}
```

I then realized that using cowplot to create a single graph combining the individual plots would make a lot of sense. For that I would need each plot not as a pdf or so, but rather as an object in my R workspace. This obviously does not work with the code above, so I tried to replace the "print" part with something I hoped would assign a new object/object name in each iteration, thus creating a series of ggplot-objects I could then work with.

This was my approach:

```
for (var in unique(plot_df$ars_label)) {
  paste0("plot_",var) <- ggplot(plot_df[plot_df$ars_label==var,],  # Deleted the dev.new and dev.off parts, and inserted the "paste0" idea - here's the major change compared to the previous version
                               aes(x = zeit, y = sch_pro_100k)) +
           scale_x_continuous(name = "Jahr",
                              limits = c(2010,2020),
                              breaks = seq(2010,2020,2)) +
           scale_y_continuous(name = "Scheidungen pro 100k EW",
                              limits = c(145,285), # limits ergeben sich aus summary(plot_df$sch_pro_100k)
                              breaks = seq(145,285,20)) +
           geom_line(color = "skyblue3", size = 0.9) + 
           ggtitle(label = var, subtitle = "Scheidungen pro 100 000 EW\n2011-2019") +
           theme_minimal()
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and I am somewhat stuck how to solve this.

Thanks for any ideas and solutions!

---

Data used for re-creating the code:

> structure(list(zeit = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L,
> 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L,
> 2019L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L,
> 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L,
> 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L,
> 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L,
> 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L,
> 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L,
> 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L,
> 2015L, 2015L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L,
> 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L,
> 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L,
> 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2012L, 2012L,
> 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L,
> 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L,
> 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L,
> 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), ars = c("DG", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
> "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "DG",
> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
> "14", "15", "16", "DG", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9",
> "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "DG", "1", "2", "3",
> "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
> "16", "DG", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11",
> "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "DG", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
> "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "DG",
> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
> "14", "15", "16", "DG", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9",
> "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "DG", "1", "2", "3",
> "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
> "16"), ars_label = c("Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Hamburg",
> "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz",
> "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
> "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein",
> "Hamburg", "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
> "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin",
> "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt",
> "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Hamburg",
> "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz",
> "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
> "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein",
> "Hamburg", "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
> "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin",
> "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt",
> "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Hamburg",
> "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz",
> "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
> "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein",
> "Hamburg", "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
> "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin",
> "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt",
> "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Hamburg",
> "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz",
> "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
> "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein",
> "Hamburg", "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen",
> "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin",
> "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt",
> "Thüringen", "Deutschland", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Hamburg",
> "Niedersachsen", "Bremen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Hessen", "Rheinland-Pfalz",
> "Bayern", "Saarland", "Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
> "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Thüringen"), pop = c(83092962L,
> 2900243L, 1844216L, 7988028L, 682094L, 17939936L, 6276945L, 4089374L,
> 13100729L, 988698L, 3657159L, 2516905L, 1608907L, 4074954L, 2201552L,
> 2138262L, 82905782L, 2893267L, 1835882L, 7972612L, 682009L, 17922393L,
> 6254536L, 4079262L, 13036963L, 992348L, 3629161L, 2507979L, 1610397L,
> 4079623L, 2215701L, 2147175L, 82657002L, 2885874L, 1820511L,
> 7954230L, 679893L, 17901117L, 6228175L, 4069866L, 12963978L,
> 995419L, 3594163L, 2499344L, 1610897L, 4081546L, 2229667L, 2154667L,
> 82348669L, 2870320L, 1798923L, 7936142L, 675121L, 17877808L,
> 6194630L, 4059428L, 12887133L, 996124L, 3547431L, 2489737L, 1611518L,
> 4083317L, 2240861L, 2164421L, 81686611L, 2844789L, 1775100L,
> 7876669L, 666689L, 17751807L, 6135030L, 4032193L, 12767541L,
> 992316L, 3494940L, 2471349L, 1605750L, 4070063L, 2240509L, 2163737L,
> 80982500L, 2823410L, 1754567L, 7808649L, 659640L, 17604977L,
> 6069657L, 4002974L, 12647906L, 989877L, 3445839L, 2453533L, 1597822L,
> 4050830L, 2240063L, 2158800L, 80645605L, 2811243L, 1740307L,
> 7784777L, 656083L, 17563093L, 6030953L, 3992322L, 12561908L,
> 992503L, 3398526L, 2449352L, 1598416L, 4048295L, 2251985L, 2165650L,
> 80425823L, 2804399L, 1726230L, 7776624L, 653478L, 17549634L,
> 6005126L, 3990156L, 12481472L, 996071L, 3350612L, 2451346L, 1603613L,
> 4052193L, 2268065L, 2176032L, 80274983L, 2801200L, 1711944L,
> 7776541L, 651825L, 17545065L, 5981590L, 3992109L, 12413388L,
> 999867L, 3302174L, 2457211L, 1610844L, 4060219L, 2287061L, 2188474L
> ), scheidungen = c(149010L, 6010L, 3079L, 15275L, 1106L, 33800L,
> 12021L, 8008L, 22317L, 1985L, 5898L, 4424L, 2837L, 6283L, 3546L,
> 3465L, 148066L, 6036L, 2802L, 15186L, 1181L, 34602L, 11949L,
> 8025L, 22464L, 1910L, 5342L, 4212L, 2858L, 6143L, 3479L, 3535L,
> 153501L, 6123L, 2912L, 15986L, 1332L, 35778L, 12500L, 8362L,
> 22599L, 2037L, 6070L, 4445L, 2976L, 6427L, 3808L, 3790L, 162397L,
> 6194L, 3204L, 17120L, 1419L, 37650L, 13264L, 8897L, 24134L, 2209L,
> 6253L, 4691L, 2866L, 6698L, 4183L, 3951L, 163335L, 6308L, 3190L,
> 17226L, 1393L, 38312L, 12834L, 8835L, 24247L, 2131L, 6427L, 4845L,
> 2573L, 7007L, 4109L, 3995L, 166199L, 6686L, 3265L, 16776L, 1382L,
> 39489L, 13149L, 9022L, 24463L, 2133L, 6405L, 4887L, 3054L, 6928L,
> 4199L, 4033L, 169833L, 6683L, 3199L, 17307L, 1404L, 40450L, 13180L,
> 9377L, 24797L, 2237L, 6628L, 5003L, 2903L, 7272L, 4220L, 4240L,
> 179147L, 7113L, 3446L, 17806L, 1391L, 43399L, 14334L, 9724L,
> 25644L, 2491L, 7267L, 5031L, 3276L, 7104L, 4620L, 4275L, 187640L,
> 7431L, 3635L, 18953L, 1566L, 44501L, 14905L, 11041L, 27004L,
> 2659L, 7930L, 5344L, 3407L, 7146L, 4808L, 4197L), sch_pro_100k = c(179.329267381274,
> 207.224015366988, 166.954413149002, 191.223666216493, 162.147739167915,
> 188.406469231551, 191.510360533667, 195.824593201796, 170.349298882528,
> 200.769092280959, 161.27272563211, 175.771433566225, 176.330887987932,
> 154.185789581919, 161.068191893719, 162.047494647522, 178.595504955251,
> 208.622294451221, 152.624188264823, 190.477098346188, 173.16487025831,
> 193.065736255198, 191.045346929013, 196.726760869981, 172.310069454059,
> 192.472801879986, 147.196555898181, 167.943989961638, 177.47176627875,
> 150.577639159305, 157.015770629701, 164.634927288181, 185.708404957634,
> 212.171425363685, 159.955089532554, 200.974827230291, 195.913180456337,
> 199.864622972969, 200.700847358978, 205.461310028389, 174.321492986181,
> 204.637444131567, 168.884939275153, 177.846666965412, 184.74179292655,
> 157.464842978616, 170.787835134125, 175.897250015896, 197.206587516308,
> 215.794754591823, 178.106567095979, 215.72194650751, 210.184544696432,
> 210.596287867058, 214.120940233719, 219.168809004618, 187.272064314072,
> 221.759539976951, 176.268403811096, 188.41347499756, 177.844740176653,
> 164.033309194461, 186.669320408539, 182.543044999101, 199.953208978152,
> 221.738765159736, 179.708185454341, 218.696507368787, 208.943000409486,
> 215.820282408433, 209.192131089824, 219.111535583738, 189.911275789128,
> 214.750140076347, 183.894430233423, 196.046774453952, 160.236649540713,
> 172.159497285423, 183.395826573337, 184.634269322011, 205.228290062668,
> 236.805848247332, 186.085797806524, 214.838700010719, 209.508216602996,
> 224.305888045182, 216.634976243303, 225.38242816466, 193.415415958974,
> 215.481317375795, 185.876356962702, 199.182158952009, 191.135182767542,
> 171.026678483175, 187.450085109213, 186.816750046322, 210.591761324129,
> 237.724024568492, 183.818142431192, 222.318507004118, 213.997314364189,
> 230.312508166984, 218.539259052425, 234.875844182909, 197.398357001182,
> 225.389746932755, 195.025725858799, 204.258105817375, 181.617301128117,
> 179.631178063852, 187.390235725371, 195.784175651652, 222.748109148973,
> 253.637232077176, 199.625774085724, 228.968251518911, 212.861029751575,
> 247.292906507338, 238.696073987457, 243.699745072624, 205.456535895766,
> 250.082574434955, 216.885751021007, 205.234185626998, 204.288690600538,
> 175.312478946585, 203.697865801906, 196.458507963118, 233.746545919543,
> 265.279166071684, 212.331711784965, 243.720183562332, 240.248532965136,
> 253.6382737824, 249.181237764541, 276.570604660344, 217.539321255406,
> 265.935369404131, 240.144825802638, 217.482340751364, 211.504031427003,
> 176.000358601346, 210.226137387678, 191.7774668559)), row.names = c(NA,
> -144L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could you try storing the plots in a list? So initialise a list outside your for loop and then inside use: mylist[[i]] <- ggplot....

Comment: Perfect! I used `plotlist <- list()` outside of the loop and then modified the ggplot-part in the loop to `plotlist[[var]] <- ggplot(...` and now I have a list of my plots! Thank you very much! Could you post this as answer so I can rate it as such?

Comment: Sure, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the plots in a list.

First initialise a list outside your for loop and then inside it use mylist[[i]] to assign each plot.